What is the difference between <cite> </cite> and <dfn> </dfn>
I'm unable to understand the difference in the results of the above two mentioned tags. The outcomes for the both is similar.
I tried both the tags and they gave me the result in italic form. So why's there 2 tags to get the same result?

The documentation defines what these tags mean: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn

There's a lot more to tags than what they render to the screen...

having an identical visual result does not demonstrate that their meanings are the same.

For an answer: The browser rendered them as "same" by chance. But it won't in general case.
You see them as "same", but it's not true. Their looks depend on your CSS configuration, or your browser's user agent Stylesheet.
Also they has different semantics, according to HTML Living Standard at the time of writing:

§ 4.5.6 The cite element
The cite element represents the title of a work (e.g. a book, a paper, an essay, a poem, a score, a song, a script, a film, a TV show, a game, a sculpture, a painting, a theatre production, a play, an opera, a musical, an exhibition, a legal case report, a computer program, etc.).


§ 4.5.8 The dfn element
The dfn element represents the defining instance of a term.

Seeing them as same will be discouraged by user agents.
